# Reduce spacing in HTML output using PHP

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, html-table

This seems like something simple so I must be missing something, but I am having issues reducing the spacing between table rows in the output from the following:

```
  <table align="center" width="100%" cellspacing="100">
                <th width="100px;"></th>
                <tbody id="ajax_res">
                    <?php
                        include 'db_connect.php';
                        $query = "SELECT INSERT_DATE,LINE_TEXT FROM DATA_TAB ORDER BY INSERT_DATE DESC";
                            $result = mysql_query($query);
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                            {
                                $insert_date = $row['INSERT_DATE'];
                                $line_text = $row['LINE_TEXT'];
                                echo  "<tr height='10'><td>".$insert_date."</td>";
                                echo  "<td align='left' width='nowrap' style='padding:0 25px 0 25px;'>".$line_text."</td></tr>";
                            }
                    mysql_close($con);
                ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The use of **cellspacing="100"** is what is causing your table to bloat.

---

On a side note, your HTML tags should be using double quotes, not single quotes and your TH tags need to be inside TR tags. Here is what I came up with while looking for your original issue.

```
<style type="text/css">
    table, tr, td, tbody {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    table {
        width: 100%;
    }

    td {
        padding: 5px;
    }

    .date {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .text {
        text-align: left;
        padding: 0px 25px;
    }
</style>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Text</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody id="ajax_res">
<?php
include 'db_connect.php';
$query = 'SELECT INSERT_DATE,LINE_TEXT FROM DATA_TAB ORDER BY INSERT_DATE DESC';
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $insert_date = $row['INSERT_DATE'];
    $line_text = $row['LINE_TEXT'];
    echo
        "\t\t", '<tr>', "\n",
        "\t\t\t", '<td class="date">', $insert_date, '</td>', "\n",
        "\t\t\t", '<td class="text">', $line_text, '</td>', "\n",
        "\t\t", '</tr>', "\n";
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to have fixed it -- could it be a CSS issue?

Comment: If you copy my code into a blank .htm file, replace the PHP with some trs and tds, you'll see it works as expected. Unless there is CSS that you haven't added to the question I can't help further.

Comment: Only relevant entry in CSS appears to be this:

`table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 10px;
 }`

Comment: That will be adding some spacing, but not nearly as much as the cellspacing was.

Comment: I've created a class with your CSS and applied it to the table. Still no fix. Absolutely no idea what is causing this. Should the class not just override any other problems in the CSS?

Comment: There any many ways CSS can be applied to a single object or a multitude of elements. Creating a class with one or two lines in it and applying that to an object won't negate everything else already applied to that element elsewhere in the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing or reducing cellspacing of table:

```
<table align="center" width="100%" cellspacing="10">
```